# How to apply velocity to a parent object that ignores child object's mass in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am making a VR data visualisation app in Unity and I have a parent with many children (just some primitive cubes) that I can toss around the scene by just setting the parent's rigidbody to the same velocity as my tracked VR controller.

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
Vector3 controllerVelocity = Player.instance.rightHand.GetTrackedObjectVelocity(); // how I ref the controller velocity in SteamVR
rb.velocity = controllerVelocity * 2f; // the 2f is just to speed up the velocity
```

The above code works fine, but the problem is I think the scale of the children objects, which can be adjusted by the player, is affecting the velocity the parent moves at. Or maybe just when the children are very large...the controller velocity is comparatively too slow? Basically I need this to not be the case; I want the parent's rigidbody to move at roughly the same velocity no matter the children's scales/masses.

So to achieve that I thought to use Rigidbody.AddForce but it doesn't seem to be making any difference i.e. larger children are still moving slower. Here is what I have so far:

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
Vector3 controllerVelocity = Player.instance.rightHand.GetTrackedObjectVelocity();
rb.AddForce(controllerVelocity  * 2f, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

I also tried ForceMode.Acceleration but then nothing moved at all? Am I using AddForce incorrectly? Or do I just need a scaling multiplier based on the size of the children? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but was able to mimic my intended result by doing the following:

```
float parentMagnitude = transform.lossyScale.magnitude;
float thrustAdjuster = parentMagnitude * 5f;
Vector3 controllerVelocity = Player.instance.rightHand.GetTrackedObjectVelocity();
rb.velocity = controllerVelocity * thrustAdjuster;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering you not with the assured answer but with a proposal.
Changing the scale you are presumably not changing the mass of the global object, but you might be changining it's [center of mass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html) which affects the inertias.

From the docs "If you don't set the center of mass from a script it will be calculated automatically from all colliders attached to the rigidbody"

What I would try is to get the center of mass value, and re-set the same center of mass after the scale modification to check if it could be that the movement described by the force applied is the same as it was before.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I have checked the center of mass before and after scaling and it doesn't ever change. However, I have also removed all children colliders to see if there is any difference and there is also no difference. So I am starting to think the velocity is the same for small and large children...it's just a physical fact that they have to move a greater distance when they're larger so the same velocity looks slower...?

Comment: i think that `they have to move a greater distance when they're larger` is not correct. An object that moves from A to B, should move the same distance not depending on the objects's size. Taken to the limit the speed perception of an external obsever could have influence, but I think it would not be that case if not comparing a worm with a whale. You can also check the observer speed perception yourself, moving the transform with some code instead of physics and comparing with your desired behaviour

Comment: I guess what I actually meant is in this instance the whale is made up of 50 worms. And when I scale up the parent, the spaces between the worms increases as well. And I think applying the same velocity at both scales means moving between worms is slower for large scales because the space is bigger and they're moving at the same velocity as if they were small. I think I just need to apply a proportional thrust, like transform.lossyscale.magnitude to account for this. Does that make physical sense?

Comment: dont think it make physical sense, because you are applying a force. This force results in an acceleration (F = m*a), that accelerates the body. If the mas does not change, speed should be the same afaik. The space/distance the object is moving has no influence when dealing with forces

Comment: By desgn children colliders' volume will contribute towards computed volume of te resulting rigidbody mass. If you want to avoid this, you can use Constraints system to make children follow the parent, without them having to be te same physics body, however this will mean the children won't respect collisions by default

Comment: @zambari I thought you could also avoid this by using Rigidbody.AddForce since there are options in it to ignore mass?

Comment: that's true, if you use forcemode velocity if I recall correctly, but the resulting object will have a larger momentum - that may or may not be a problem